# Chrome debugging of react-native not working

Tags: react-native, google-chrome-devtools

I have been developing with React Native and in the past I was able to debug with Chrome devtools, though it was often sub-optimal and really affected application performance.

Know Chrome devtools just don't work. I try setting breakpoints and they don't set, or jump to some random line far below where I wanted it. I try adding "debugger;" to the code and the debugger does not stop on it.

Nothing seams to work and I have been using console.warn as my debugging, which is not awesome. I have read the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html) etc. Any help would be welcome.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I am having similar problems: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50115947/react-native-debugging-with-async-await

Answer (score 4):

Ensure that "JS Dev mode" is on and and "JS minify" is off in Dev settings (Shake menu). In the past this has happened to me on many occasions where I would turn Dev mode off and forget. Breakpoints will not be hit if it's off.

Comment: I have made sure of that. The problem seems like there is just inconsistent behavior for the Chrome dev tools. There is talk on RN github too [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10729#issuecomment-259638512) and [here](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/199#issuecomment-239482081).